# OpenGL - Practice of binding to default texture?

Tags: c++, opengl

I've noticed that some choose to bind the default texture to every texture unit they have used during each render loop. Is this common / best practice?

Pseudo Example:

```
Tick() {

  glUseProgram(someProgram);

  glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
  glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, imgTexture1);

  glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
  glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, imgTexture2);

  .
  .
  .

  //Is the following really necessary: ???

  glUseProgram(0);

  glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
  glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);

  glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
  glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);

}
```

If it's not required here, then should such calls be made before resources are released?

Comment: What OpenGL version are you targeting?

Comment: @tambre - Asking more generally the best practice overall. If the answer to this question is version dependent, then which versions & how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not necessary for deleting objects. When you delete an object, it is automatically unbound from every binding point. This is only true of the context that issued the `glDelete*` command; other contexts that share access to that object won't have it unbound. And if the object is attached to another object (such as a texture attached to a framebuffer), then that also won't be unattached.

It is not a bad idea to clean up after yourself, mainly to avoid errors. If a shader tries to access a texture unit that has something bound to it, it may "work", thus hiding the error. Whereas if it tries to access a unit that has nothing bound to it, it's a lot more likely to visibly fail.

Of course, this is primarily for debugging, so you can `#ifdef` around such code to remove it in release builds.

However, the above assumes that you're unbinding the texture essentially after you're done rendering with it. I bring that up because the code you've displayed that unbinds from every texture unit is *incorrect*. Why?

Because each texture unit has *multiple* binding points, one for each *type* of texture. So if you bound a texture to `GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP`, calling `glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE2D, 0)` doesn't do anything to the texture bound to the cube map target.

So if you're going to write code that unbinds textures from every texture unit, you have to call `glBindTexture` with [*every* texture target that exists](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Texture#Theory):

```
void UnbindFromTextureUnit(int unit)
{
  static const GLenum allTargets[] = {/*Every texture target that exists*/};

  glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0 + unit);
  for(auto target : allTargets)
    glBindTexture(target, 0);
}
```

Or you could use the [multibind `glBindTextures` from GL 4.4](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Sampler_(GLSL)#Multibind_and_textures). Or the direct-state-access 4.5 `glBindTextureUnit()`.

Comment: Very clear and well presented answer - thankyou for the clarity. Indeed -
 the example I gave was assuming a program that only makes `GL_TEXTURE2D` bindings. Further, good idea to simply remove such code for release through a pre-process statement. +1